# ng-repeat flickering on updating realtime data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, dom, angularjs-ng-repeat

In the following code in angular.js 1.x, I need to create a dashboard dataset which makes a call every few second and update the dom. However it is flickering because of I think `$scope.DOMdataArray = []`

I have already tried `track by $index` but didn't help. Is there any way to resolve this issue or write a code in such a way that DOM generated by ng-repeat doesn't flicker?

```
function someDataInterval () {
    $scope.DOMdataArray = []
    _.map(urlsArray,function(url) {
        $http.get(url).then(function(res) {
           // some work on response 
           $scope.DOMdataArray.push(/*some data for ng-repeat*/)
        }) 
    })
}
someDataInterval ()
setInterval(someDataInterval,5000)
```

Comment: How many items has your array? It is a big array?

Comment: @The.Bear 10-20 not big but its dynamic. I should not hard code the size.

Comment: You're clearing the array before making the network call, making the repeat blank while waiting for the network response.

Comment: @jonas that is true, but what else i can do? how to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this ?

```
            function someDataInterval () {
                _.map(urlsArray,function(url) {
                    $http.get(url).then(function(res) {
                       // some work on response 
                       $scope.DOMdataArray = [];
                       $scope.DOMdataArray.push(/*some data for ng-repeat*/)
                    }) 
                })
            }
            someDataInterval ()
            setInterval(someDataInterval,5000)
```

If this doesn't work you can always use a small loading icon so that flickering is not visible. use ng-show for showing list.

```
            function someDataInterval () {
                $scope.loading = true;
                _.map(urlsArray,function(url) {
                    $http.get(url).then(function(res) {
                       // some work on response 
                       $scope.DOMdataArray = [];
                       $scope.DOMdataArray.push(/*some data for ng-repeat*/)
                       $scope.loading = false;
                    }) 
                })
            }
            someDataInterval ()
            setInterval(someDataInterval,5000)
```

and HTML :

```
      <h1 ng-show="!loading" ng-repeat="x in DOMdataArray">{{x.name}}</h1>
      <img ng-show="loading" src="img/image-loading.gif" />
```

Comment: first one yes, I tried it but didn't help. second one Ill update you, should try it at workplace.